# Laravel what's the point of RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware

Tags: laravel, middleware

I'm finding it hard to understand this middleware `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated`

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Specifically the if condition. Someone created a `[null]` guard which always fails the `if` check, so why not avoid the loop completely with simply `[]`?

Furthermore this handle method is only executed when user is NOT authenticated, so maybe it should've been named `RedirectIfUnauthenticated`?

And yet the logic that redirects users to /login page is not present, its already implemented somewhere else.

So what is the use case for this middleware? I guess I'd have to implement a guard that would only get applied to unauthenticated requests? But then what is the point of the `return redirect` to the authenticated home page?

Comment: Auth::guard(null)->check() doesn't always return false. When accessing a page that has a 'guest' guard but user is authenticated. That's why LoginController applies this to all login routes except for logout - to prevent users from seeing login form when users are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

> Furthermore this handle method is only executed when user is NOT
> authenticated, so maybe it should've been named
> RedirectIfUnauthenticated?

This is not true, its executed when the 'guest' middleware is specified on the route.

`Auth::guard(null)->check()` doesn't always return false. When accessing a page that has a 'guest' middleware but user is authenticated.

That's why LoginController applies this to all login routes except for logout in order to RedirectIfAuthenticated when accessing a page intended for UNauthenticated users.

I was confusing this with `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php` which I've now renamed to `RedirectIfUnauthenticated` where the `redirectTo` method is only run when user is NOT authenticated and would need redirecting because you decided to put 'auth' middleware on the route.